# Modualrize Python program with appJar GUI

Tags: python, appjar

How do you modularize an appJar app? When I try to use the [example code](http://appjar.info/#upcoming-in-v10) and move the `press()` function into an own file, this functions doesn't know the app variable. I guess it's best if you look at the Image below - if not I'll update the question!

[image: Example]

Comment: create `def press(app)` and send `app` as parameter. It is not good to use variables which are not send as arguments.

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image. Python can't load image to run code.

Comment: as for me putting `press` in separated file is wrong idea. In separated file should be rather new widgets or classes which can be used in other projects. And you have to put function in separated file then you have to get all values as arguments and it shouldn't use unknow variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me it is not good idea to put `press()` in separated file. I would rather keep `press()` in current file and it could use function from other file - but this file should get all values as arguments

**modules/methods.py**

```
def display(app):
    print("User:", app.entry("Username"), "Pass:", app.entry("Password"))
```

**main.py**

```
from appJar import gui 
from modules import methods

def press():
    methods.display(app)

with gui("Login Window", "400x200", bg='orange', font={'size':18}) as app:
    app.label("Welcome to appJar", bg='blue', fg='orange')
    app.entry("Username", label=True, focus=True)
    app.entry("Password", label=True, secret=True)
    app.buttons(["Submit", "Cancel"], [press, app.stop])
```

Or event other function should get only values from widgets

**modules/methods.py**

```
def display(username, password):
    print("User:", username, "Pass:", password)
```

**main.py**

```
def press():
    methods.display(app.entry("Username"), app.entry("Password"))
```

---

If you really want `press()` in other file then it should get `app` as argument

**modules/methods.py**

```
def press(app):
    print("User:", app.entry("Username"), "Pass:", app.entry("Password"))
```

but then you have to use `lambda:methods.press(app)` to assign to button function with argument.

**main.py**

```
app.buttons(["Submit", "Cancel"], [lambda:methods.press(app), app.stop])
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of passing app as a variable.

Comment: in your first example of main.py you have two typos: It has to be `from modules import methods` and in `def press():` it need to be `methods.display(app)`

Comment: I corrected typos - all because you put code as image and I had to write it manually :)